# Need help expanding and simplifying an algebra statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory

***$3(2^k + 1) - 2(2^{k-1} + 1)$***

I generally know how to expand terms but I'm not too sure how the powered terms interact with each other.

What I have so far:

***$3(2^k + 1) - 2(2^{k-1} + 1)$*** 
 = ***$(6^k + 3) - (4^{k-1} + 2)$***
 = ***$(6^k + 1) - 4^{k-1}$***

Comment: $3(2^k+1)=3*2^k+3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Step-by-Step Solution:**

First, let $$S=3(2^k+1)-2(2^{k-1}+1)$$

Using the distributive property, $$S=3(2^k+1)-2(2^{k-1}+1)=3\cdot 2^k+1\cdot 3-2\cdot 2^{k-1}-2\cdot1$$

Now, using $$a^m \cdot a^n=a^{m+n}\tag{$*$}$$ We get $$2 \cdot 2^{k-1}=2^{(k-1)+1}=2^k$$

So, $$S=3\cdot 2^k+3-2^k-2$$

Substitute $2^k=m$ and then simplify to get

$$S=3m+3-m-2=2m+1$$

Now, back-substitute $m=2^k$ and use $(*)$ to get

$$\color{red}{S=2^{k+1}+1}$$

---

*Note:*

$\color{blue}{3 \cdot 2^k \neq 6^k}$ because when performing operations preference is given to exponentiation over multiplication. However, brackets are given given the highest priority.

If there were no such rules $3 \cdot 2^k$ would be ambiguous as it could mean $6^k$ or $3 \cdot 2^k$ depending on the order preference.
In such a scenario, brackets rescue us from the ambiguity.

So, $(3\cdot2)^k=6^k$ and not what you claim.

It would be better if you write $3\cdot2^k=3 \cdot (2^k)$ to avoid any confusion(for now at least).

Similarly, $\color{blue}{2 \cdot 2^{k-1} \neq 4^{k-1}}$ which shall occupy the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You made several mistakes.

Observe: $3*2^k\neq 6^k$ and $2*2^{k-1}\neq 4^{k-1}$.

$$S=3(2^k + 1) - 2(2^{k-1} + 1)$$
$$S=3*2^k+3-2*2^{k-1}-2$$
$$S=3*2^k+3-2^k-2$$
$$S=(3*2^k-2^k)+(3-2)$$
$$S=(3-1)*2^k+1$$
$$S=2^{k+1}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not expand everything:
$$3(2^k+1)-2(2^{k-1}+1)=3(2^k+1)-(2^k+1)-1=2(2^k+1)-1=2^{k+1}+1.$$